# View not displaying nodes to anonymous users (workflow + views)

Tags: views, workflows

After changing from WorkflowNode to WorkflowField, and migrating the content, the nodes are not displayed to any other user but to our Administrator role on the View we created for that content type.

Redid the view, but no success. Using [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel), it made me suspect node_access table (as reported by devel), so I rebuild permissions (no result).

Not sure I'm looking in the right place. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you temporary disable (not uninstall) any modules you have in place related to accessing nodes, and then enable them again?